# Script is not running in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to run a file in multi processing but it is running in single process

```
import multiprocessing as mp

f2 = open('main-urls.txt','r')
pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
pool.apply(main_data_to_csv, args=(x,)) for link in f2]

def main_data_to_csv(self,link):
    data_store = []
    link = re.sub(r"[\s\n]*","",link)
    print (link)
```

Please let me know how to run this script in multiple process?

Comment: Have you read the Python Standard Library documentation for multiprocessing (e.g. for 2.7 https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) and based your code on one of the examples there? If you have, then to have the best chance of getting help you need to post a potentially runnable as-posted, minimal code snippet here which as-posted shows your problem, and describe what is going wrong in more detail than "it doesn't work". See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please correct your code: it's missing definition of `cube` and this line: `(cube, args=(x,)) for link in f2]` is missing some brackets...

Answer (score 0):

The `apply` function is a blocking one. You should use [apply_async](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) to run parallel tasks in a `Pool`.